# How to awake a Thread every second, Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to launch a thread that needs to execute a task every second. 
So what I did from now is making a loop on this code:

```
// execute my task
..

lastScan.setTime(lastScan.getTime() + 1000);
long timeToSleep = (lastScan.getTime() - new Date().getTime());
try {
    Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is something more elegant, and maybe more safe, for example a function that awake my thread when the current Date reach a given time.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: that's what timers are for.

Comment: [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, this will help you do a timed loop more elegantly.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10); //number of threads
```

From there, the class has different methods for passing `Runnable` objects for which you can run on a timed delay in a separate thread

Answer (score 2):

I would go with :

```
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
```

[Scheduled Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Timer and TimerTask,
This is a sample code that prints the same line every 5 seconds

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimeReminder {
    Timer timer;

    public TimeReminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer(); //At this line a new Thread will be created
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new TimeReminder(5);
        System.out.println("Timertask is scheduled with Java timer.");
    }
}
```